# Magento 2 Item (Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node) with the same ID "1" already exists

Tags: magento2

When clicking on Add New CMS page or open an existing page in backend below error appearing.

Item (Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node) with the same ID "1" already exists.

Could someone help asap, please?

Comment: Which magento 2 version are you using ?

Comment: Could you find a solution for that?